# Error messages while installing lwip

Tags: lwip

When I try to install lwip by using 'npm install lwip' command i got these error messages. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEs0g.png) Can someone please tell me how i can resolve these errors.

Comment: can someone please help me for fix these?